# Is there a global annotation/identifier to interpret the Python script in UTF-8?

Tags: python, encoding

I'm working on a flask application. Running the applications using `flask run`. Locally, my python code runs without any issues.
But on the server it produces the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<file_path>", line 43
SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xd8' in file <file_path> on line 43, but no encoding declared; see http://python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/ for details
```

I had to declare the utf-8 encoding:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

in every file of my project because many files contain non-ascii characters.

Is there a way to tell python/flask to interpret the scripts as utf-8 without having to change the header of every file in my project?

Comment: If you use Python 3 (as you should), UTF-8 is the default encoding.

Comment: There are various ways you can change the default encoding from things like `site.py`, but these are intended for your *local* usage; if you are distributing your source (really, that includes running your code on a machine other than your development machine), the right thing to do is to declare how Python should interpret your file *in the file itself*.